# Austria National Visa D 180 days calculation

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, austria

I am in Austria on National Visa D which allows to stay for 180 days. I travelled outside Europe for 7 days in between. My question is whether the 180 days will be calculated from start of my stay in Austria, irrespective of the stay outside Europe during that time or can I stay in Austria for 7 days more?

Example:
Arrival in Austria: 1st July 
180 days would be 28th December
If I travelled outside Europe for 7 days then till when can I stay in Austria:
28 December or 4 January?
P.S. My Visa is valid till 15th January.

Comment: Please upload a scan of your visa with personal information blacked out. Thank you.